# Using a link, not a button, to revert to previous tab in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have searched around for help but have been unsuccessful. I have found different codes to use a button on a worksheet to go back to the previous worksheet the user was on. What the company I work for wants are links on the top of almost each worksheet to function as a navigation pane for the users. I have created links at the top of the necessary sheets which all work as expected. I originally added code to my workbook to use a back link (previous sheet user was on, not the sheet before the current sheet) at cell "A5" and it worked for awhile but as I've been progressing on other items within the workbook, the code stopped working. I have compared the code on the working workbook with the nonworking workbook and they're the same and I don't believe other code is causing it to malfunction. Looking at the code below, does anyone have a suggestion for me?

On worksheets that will have a back button I have:

```
Option Explicit 

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range) 
 If Selection.Count = 1 Then
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A5")) Is Nothing Then 
   Call SelectLast 
  End If 
 End If
End Sub
```

In the ThisWorkbook object I have the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object) 
  LastSheet = Sh.Name 
End Sub
```

Finally, I have the following in it's own module:

```
Public LastSheet As String 
Sub SelectLast() 
  Application.Sheets(LastSheet).Select 
End Sub
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `if target.cells.count=1` maybe and `Application.Sheets(LastSheet).activate`

Comment: What does it do instead of working?

Comment: @TimWilliams I get a Compile error: "Expected variable or procedure, not module". It then highlights the first line in yellow "Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)" and my "Call SelectLast" module gets highlighted in blue. And it doesn't appear to be doing it anymore but just flipping through the tabs at one point was causing me to get an error, though I don't recall what it said. I eventually just marked all my code re: this as a comment so I could deal with it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a workbook-level name "LastSheet":

[image]

Then add this code in the `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    'EDIT
    ThisWorkbook.Names("lastsheet").RefersToR1C1 = "='" & Sh.Name & "'!R1C1"
End Sub
```

For your "Previous sheet" hyperlinks use:

```
=HYPERLINK("#LastSheet","Previous sheet")
```

If you wanted to get fancy with your "back" link and show the destination sheet name in the link:

```
=HYPERLINK("#lastsheet",
            "<< back to - " & SUBSTITUTE(MID(CELL("address",lastsheet),1+
            FIND("]",CELL("address",lastsheet)),200),"!$A$1",""))
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but what do you mean by "Add a workbook-level name "LastSheet""? Do you mean declare it as a public variable?

Comment: Formulas tab >> Define name; choose "Workbook" for scope and enter "LastSheet" as the name.  "Refers to" is not important when you're creating the name, so just accept whatever is already populated.

Comment: Ah! I thought you meant doing this in VBA. I attempted your solution but without success. I believe it's because the named range is static in what it refers to. VBA needs to determine the sheet the user was last on, not the sheet that is before it.

Comment: My bad - I did not fully test my code...   See update above which now properly re-points the name to the correct place.

Comment: I have not applied the Previous Sheet link to all sheets yet but just tried it on three of them and it's working perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: I just wanted to add a little extra code for anyone else that may come across this and use it. The coding Tim provided that shows the back link with the name of the last sheet would leave an apostrophe at the end of the name. To remove the last apostrophe, use:
=SUBSTITUTE(HYPERLINK("#lastsheet","Back to "&SUBSTITUTE(MID(CELL("address",LastSheet),1+FIND("]",CELL("address",LastSheet)),200),"!$A$1","")),"'","")

Answer (score 0):

Craig, this should do the trick for you

I made a label look like a hyperlink & operate as one. I have basically stored the name of the sheet in the label's captions and have the workbook select the sheet that matches that text

```
Private Sub Label1_Click()
    Dim strLoc As String
    strLoc = Label1.Caption
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strLoc).Select
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't think of adding a label! Probably because I've never done made a user form and never had a need for one. I will give this a try now and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I gave it a go and could not make it work. I believe the reason is because the caption I need to read "Back", "Previous Tab" or something similar, not the name of a sheet. Now that I think about it, it might be because I wasn't specific enough in my original description so I'll go up and change it. But I don't want the link to select the sheet before it, I want the link to select whatever sheet the user was last on, which may or may not be the sheet before the current one.